# Добавление элемента в массив без перезаписи

Tags: javascript

Подскажите кто знает, как правильно добавить элемент в существующий массив, чтобы текущие элементы в этом массиве не удалялись.

Как все происходит: В переменной приходит значение "1", которое необходимо записывать в создаваемый массив. Далее в этой же переменной будет приходить следующее значение "2", которое необходимо добавить в созданный массив с первым значением "1" и при этом его не перезаписать.

Возможно не совсем полно описал процесс. У меня поток с данными и процесс устроен таким образом, что когда приходит значение, то должен задействоваться этот же код. То есть я наперед не буду знать сколько раз поменяется значение в переменной, поэтому здесь как-то через цикл необходимо

Пример кода:

```
var value = "1"

newArray=[];
for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(value);
}
```

Но так newArray после попытки записи приходит пустым

Comment: без примера твоего кода ничего не понятно

Comment: Дык Вы посмотрите что у Вас в цикле. пока `i = 0` и `i <` длины массива `newArray` (у которого длина 0(!)) `i++`, т.е. у Вас получается, что-то типа: `if(0 < 0) делай`. А 0 не меньше 0 :) И зачем Вам цикл? Снизу ведь дали правильный ответ.

Comment: @meine, более того, если бы в цикл все-таки зашел - он стал бы бесконечным

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы были правы, через цикл неверно, я себе усложнял, все работает через просто newArray.push(value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arr = [];  
let variable = null;  

variable = "1";
arr.push(variable);
variable = "2";
arr.push(variable);

console.log(arr); // ["1", "2"]
```

Метод массива `push` добавляет новый элемент в конец массива.

https://learn.javascript.ru/array#konets-massiva
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Возможно не совсем полно описал процесс. У меня поток с данными и процесс устроен таким образом, что когда приходит значение, то должен  задействоваться этот же код. То есть я наперед не буду знать сколько раз поменяется значение в переменной, поэтому здесь как-то через цикл необходимо

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```js
var a = [];
a.push("first");
a.push("second");

//Вывод в консоль
console.log(a);
```